# Can not get newly added files from Resources.resx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resx

I am trying to add new file to `Resources.resx`, however `Resources.Designer.cs` is not being updated with new file and I can not get that file via `Assembly`. It shows only one file, which was added some time ago.

I've tried seting `Access Modifier` in `Resources.resx` to `Internal` and `Public` hoping to solve that problem, but then I get error in `Resources.Designer.cs` 
`Ambiguity between 'Resources.resourceCulture' and 'Resources.resourceCulture`.

Some post suggest to clicking `Run Custom tool`, but the is no such option when I click right-button on `Resources.resx` file.

Does any one know what I'm missing to make `Resources.Designer.cs` update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got that solved, so if someone else gets this problem, when this is what I did.

For `Resources.resx` I set `Custom Tool` and `Build Action`, which are under file properties, to `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator` and `Embedded Resource` respectively. And then set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` for each added files.

I don't know if this is the proper way, but I seems to be working properly.